# How to plot uncomensated loop gain in LTspice

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics, pid-controller, bode-plot, compensation

I want to plot an uncompensated loop gain of a dcm flyback dc-dc converter. I know that I can derive the control to output transfer function and then plot the uncompensated loop gain but that just seems too much work to me.

I want to know if we can plot the uncompensated loop gain in ltspice or any other simulation software directly if we have the power stage.

On internet, I found one way by having a compensator loop gain as unity to plot this but wouldn't it make the power stage to not be at the desired dc condition? And if this is true(which is not AFAIK), then wouldn't it make the bode plot useless to design the compensator?

Comment: Ray Ridley has done a lot of work on this, see ridleyengineering.com

Comment: Since it's an SMPS you should use SIMetrix because it allows for some very nice plots in time domain. Otherwise, see [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/529358/95619), the answers in there can be applied here. too.